# Assign api json results to SwiftUI Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I have these struct:

```
 struct Problems: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var type: String
}
```

and this state:

```
@State private var issues = [Problems]()
```

I fetch the results from api like this:

```
let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([Problems].self, from: data)
                            self.issues = decoded
                            print(decoded)
```

and it prints:

```
Premier_Service.AddTaskView.Problems(id: 2, type: "Door"), 
Premier_Service.AddTaskView.Problems(id: 3, type: "Water"),
 Premier_Service.AddTaskView.Problems(id: 4, type: "Elevator"),
```

I want to assign the issues to picker, but I don't know how after trying many other codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example ... I created some dummy data.

Create another State variable, which holds your selected value and then pass all your other `Problems` object to the Picker.

```
struct Problems: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var type: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var issues = [Problems(id: 0, type: "Big Problem"), Problems(id: 1, type: "World Problem")]
    @State var selectedIssue: Problems? = nil
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Choose", selection: $selectedIssue, content: {
            ForEach(issues, id:\.self) { problem in
                Text(problem.type).tag(problem as Problems?)
            }
        })
        .onAppear(perform: {
            selectedIssue = issues.first
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to get selected picker value?

Comment: The selected picker value is stored in selectedIssue variable

Comment: could you check it in your code? because it's not work with me:   Button(action: {
                    print(selectedIssue ?? "no selection")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Print Selected")
                })

Comment: You are right! It is due to wrong typing. I fix my answer. You have to add .tag() inside the Foreach or make the State of the selection non optional. Selection and the state has to be the same type